# Postgres: inserting dynamic number of columns and values in table

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgres SQL. My requirement is to pass a dynamic number of columnId, columnValue pair and insert this combination in a table(Example: employeeId, employeeName combination). The length of list can be anything. I am thinking of building dynamic query at the code-side and pass it as string to function and execute the statement. Is there any better approach for this problem. Any example or idea will be much appreciated.

Comment: you should show a example table with require table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to pass that information as a structured JSON value, this gets quite easy. Postgres has a feature to map a JSON value to a table type using the function `json_populate_record`

Sample table:

```
create table some_table 
( 
  id integer primary key, 
  some_name text, 
  some_date date, 
  some_number integer
);
```

The insert function:

```
create function do_insert(p_data text)
 returns void
as 
$$
  insert into some_table (id, some_name, some_date, some_number)
  select (json_populate_record(null::some_table, p_data::json)).*;
$$
language sql;
```

Then you can use:

```
select do_insert('{"id": 42, "some_name": "Arthur"}');
select do_insert('{"id": 1, "some_value": 42}');
```

Note that columns that are not part of the passed JSON string are explicitly set to `NULL` using this approach.

If the passed string contains column names that do not exist, they are simply ignored, so

```
select do_insert('{"id": 12, "some_name": "Arthur", "not_there": 123}');
```

will ignore the `not_there` "column".

Online example: https://rextester.com/JNIBL25827

---

**Edit**

A similar approach can be used for updating:

```
create function do_update(p_data text)
 returns void
as 
$$
  update some_table 
     set id = t.id,
         some_name = t.some_name, 
         some_date = t.some_date, 
         some_number = t.some_number
  from json_populate_record(null::some_table, p_data::json) as t;
$$
language sql;
```

or using `insert on conflict` to cover both use cases with one function:

```
create function do_upsert(p_data text)
 returns void
as 
$$
  insert into some_table (id, some_name, some_date, some_number)
  select (json_populate_record(null::some_table, p_data::json)).*
  on conflict (id) do update
     set id = excluded.id,
         some_name = excluded.some_name, 
         some_date = excluded.some_date, 
         some_number = excluded.some_number
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance about postgres since I am only a couple of days old in this technology but this has to be the greatest feature of postgres. Saved hours of coding. I am indeed passing JSON!

Comment: Just one question though. How do we update the record using the same approach?